# Issue with VideoWriter and writeVideo in Matlab

Tags: matlab, video

I'm trying to create a movie in Matlab where I run through my code several times, and the output of each runthrough is added to the video. However, I keep getting a strange error when I actually try to add the frame to the movie. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
writerobj = VideoWriter('RHI_P.avi');
writerobj.FrameRate = 60;
open(writerobj);

\\ Runs through code and generates a pcolor figure

figure(14);
\\ Plotting script goes here....

fig = figure;
F = getframe(fig);

writerobj = writeVideo(writerobj,F);

>> Error using VideoWriter/writeVideo: Too many output arguments.
```

However, if I look at 'help writeVideo', it says this: "writeVideo(OBJ,FRAME) writes a FRAME to the video file associated with OBJ."

From my point of view (though I could be wrong!), I'm following the example given. I've been stuck on this for a couple days now. Does anyone have any advice?

Also, I've been using getframe(gcf) as a workaround for now. However, I can't keep doing that, because my code takes several days to run, and gcf captures the screensaver once that kicks on.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but how about `writerobj.writeVideo(F);`?

Comment: Do you have an example that reproduces your error? And the full error message?

Comment: @excaza The code that I'm using to create the pcolor plot takes quite a while to run, but I can try to create a toy example that yields the same error.

Comment: @A.Donda Just tried that, and I got the same error as before (Too many output arguments).

Comment: When your code represents what you really do, then you create a new figure with `fig = figure;` and then store the empty figure with `getframe(fig)`. In this case, you need to provide the handle of `figure(14);` like this: `fig = figure(14); getframe(fig)`. I'm not sure if this is the problem here.

Comment: Two issues: 1) I was setting writerobj equal to the writeVideo(writerobj,F), and this was causing the error I was getting. 2) The other error was the one that @Matt pointed out, that I was grabbing the wrong figure; I thought that 'figure' would grab the most recently created figure, but this appears to not be the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

writeVideo does not have an output argument which is what the error states.

You just need to say

```
writeVideo(writerObj, F);
```

Hope this helps.